# getting 500 internal server error when sending ajax data to the server side method in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

when I am submitting ajax data to the server method at that time 500 internal error is coming while the same ajax method if I call without data at that time it is working perfect. I am really confused that how the ajax data will send to the server method.

Here is my code

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="dropdwn_consignor" runat="server" onfocusout="blurFunction()"        ></asp:ComboBox>

<script>
    function blurFunction() {
        var c = $find("<%=dropdwn_consignor.ClientID %>");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Booking123.aspx/GetCnorGSTNo",
            data: "{ TinNo1: '"+ c.get_textBoxControl().value +"'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: "true",
            cache: "false"
        });

    }
</script>     

[WebMethod]
public static void GetCnorGSTNo(string Param1)
{
 // here is the code
}
```

Please help me to solve this issues.

Thank You.

Comment: step through your code and you will see what error it is throwing (500 is internal error so it'ssomething in your c# that is failing).  If you don't know how to debug, you can try looking at your event log.  If you don't know how to do that then try posting your form without ajax and the page will show you your error - if you have removed friendly error pages

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error the problem is on the server, so it's the `// here is the code` section we actually need to see. Also note that your parameter is named `Param1`, not `TinNo1`, and you can give the object directly to jQuery for it to encode; there's no need to hack together an ugly JSON-like string

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan first of all your sence are too bad. I already tell you that the debug point is not coming to the method then why are you want to see the code. hehehe. First read question carefully then give comment else not need to give. understand.

Comment: Nothing in your question states you have debugged the server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check the Parameter names:**

GetCnorGSTNo() has a string parameter of "Param1" not "TinNo1"

**Try :**

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 
    Param1: c.get_textBoxControl().value 
}),
```

Comment: `data: { Param1: c.get_textBoxControl().value }` would work - no need to overcomplicate it.

Comment: Thank you. @JAck and Rory McCrossan